# Struts 2 project is built in My Eclipse but not Deployed on Tomcat server

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, struts2, myeclipse

I build a Struts 2 + Hibernate web project using MyEclipse IDE.

When I run it in MyEclipse Tomcat environment it works fine ,but i want to run it on Tomcat server separately (means apart from MyEclipse ), so I export a `.war` file of project and deploy it on Tomcat manger - it is not working.

second issue is that when  I copied my project from `"My Eclipse\.metadata\.me_tcat\webapps\.."` path and put it in tomcat `webapps` , but it is not working also - `"HTTP Status 404 - /.."` error occurred.

Is there any `.jar` file issue or something else?

Comment: Define not working. Post stacktrace of the error.

Comment: hi Aleksandar , not working means- it not run successfully as it on myeclipse ide.

Comment: please post error log or try to create war file using maven

Comment: I think no one will be able to help you with this statement `it is not working... `. There should be some explanation what is not working, what is in server console? is server able to load war file?

Comment: Thanks - Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye and Umesh Awasthi
i wrote there is 404 error occured in both case either i deploy .war file or manually put it webapps folder
 
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.36

Comment: have you got any error in tomcat log while server is starting ?

Comment: It's impossible to help with the information given. You can't just arbitrarily "copy your project" into `webapps` and expect it to work. Without knowing what's in your WAR file it's impossible to help. "Not working" is not a sufficient description, e.g., "My car isn't working, it won't start. Tell me what's wrong, right now." See? Impossible. I suspect either (a) not getting the required libs in the war, or (b) something else entirely.

Comment: As others have mentioned, this is really not enough information to help. Your 404 means that the application has not been deployed correctly, or you are using the wrong URL to access it. You should describe exactly how you are exporting the project and how you are deploying it (in detail). You should check the war file to ensure it has everything needed. You should try deploying directly from MyEclipse, as Roman C mentioned in his answer, and check it works. Make sure that what gets deployed when using MyEclipse is also what gets exported to the WAR file. As much info as possible, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MyEclipse you can deploy your application to the local server (not embedded). For this to work you should add a server on the Servers view and configure deploy configuration by right-clicking add deployment. There you can edit a context path that your application will run after deployment. You can use excellent <kbd>Deploy</kbd> button from the toolbar or the servers view. Note that MyEclipse *copies* files to the server, and you better not use `"/"` context path because in this case your `webapps/ROOT` folder will be overridden.  If the application is deployed fine you can see in the logs the context path at which it has been started. Then you can access the application using this context path in the browser.

```
http://localhost:8080/yourappname/index.action
```

This url supposed to invoke the `index` action name, that should be configured in `struts.xml`. This is an example of index action

```
<action name="index">
  <result>/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The second issue you should not copy/modify files in the `metadata` folder. This folder is used internally by MyEclipse unless you know what are you doing.